# how to force pandas .loc to return series

Tags: python, pandas, series, pandas-loc, type-coercion

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` with `NAME` index and one of the columns called `CLASS`:

```
df = 
        CLASS
NAME    
John    Math
John    Science
Lisa    Music
```

Now if I extract `df.loc['John', 'CLASS']`, it returns a `Series`, but if I extract `df.loc['Lisa', 'CLASS']` it returns a `str`.

Is there a way for me to force the returned value to be `Series` (i.e. `['Music', ]`)? I need to iterate through that returned object right afterwards and I don't want to go through `Math`, `Science` in John's case (desired) but `M, u, s, i, c` in Lisa's case (not desired).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To force `loc` to return a `Series`, wrap your index value(s) inside a list literal.

```
df.loc[['John'], 'CLASS']

NAME
John       Math
John    Science
Name: CLASS, dtype: object
```

```
df.loc[['Lisa'], 'CLASS']

NAME
Lisa    Music
Name: CLASS, dtype: object
```

This causes a `Series` with 1 (or more) rows to be returned regardless. Also works when the list is empty, returning an empty list:

```
df.loc[[], 'CLASS']
Series([], Name: CLASS, dtype: object)
```